# Scheme: cannot use #t in an if statement

Tags: scheme, iteration, mit-scheme

Apologies if the question title is a bit confusing. Maybe after you are through reading it, you can suggest me a better title.

As a part of a homework assignment for an online course, I wrote an iterative procedure in `mit-scheme` to display number from 1 to a given number.

The code below works fine:

```
(define (count2-iter num)
    (define (iter counter)
        (cond ((> counter num) #t)
              (else (display counter)
                (iter (+ counter 1)))))
    (iter 1))
```

The output:

```
1 ]=> (load "count2-iter.scm")

;Loading "count2-iter.scm"... done
;Value: count2-iter

1 ]=> (count2-iter 10)
12345678910
;Value: #t
```

Personally I do not like using `cond` for 2 branches only and I tried to use `if` for this.

```
(define (count2-iter1 num)
    (define (loop idx)
        (if (> idx num)
            #t
            ((display idx)
             (loop (+ idx 1)))))
    (loop 1))
```

The output:

```
1 ]=> (count2-iter1 5)
5
;The object #!unspecific is not applicable.
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 2) => Specify a procedure to use in its place.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
```

Why is this? Shouldn't #t be evaluated the same way it was used in `cond`? Would really appreciate an explanation as I am still new to Scheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(define (count2-iter1 num)
  (define (loop idx)
    (if (> idx num)
        #t
        (begin ; notice the difference!
          (display idx)
          (loop (+ idx 1)))))
  (loop 1))
```

Here's why: when you use an `if`, there can be only one expression in the consequent part and one in the alternative part. If more than one expression is needed, we have to surround them with a `(begin ...)`. You surrounded the expressions between `(...)`, which is not ok, because parenthesis are used for *function application* (that's why the error message states that `The object #!unspecific is not applicable`).

On the other hand, a `cond` has an implicit `begin` for each of its clauses when a condition is met. Personally, I prefer to stick with using `cond` when I need more than one expression after a condition - it's less verbose.

Comment: +1 ,but personally I think it would be much more natural to invert the condition. Even better are `when` or `unless` forms if there's no else branch

Comment: thank you...i have written cond with begin a few times before but never knew that it was implicit there.